# How to create Qualtrics Survey to display photos was uploaded by participants in another Block

Tags: qualtrics

I need help with Qualtrics Survey, I have an issue displaying photos that were uploaded by the participants in another question.

In my survey I'm asking the participants to upload 3 photos. Then I'd like to display the photos to the participants and ask them questions regarding the photos.

So far I couldn't find any functionality in Qualtrics to make my logic work!
I hope you can help me out, and give me some advice how to make it display uploaded photos in a subsequent question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html and pipe the url of the uploaded file into an img tag as the source:

```
<img src="${q://QID1/UploadedFileLink}" alt="Uploaded image">
```

Comment: how I can get the url of the uploaded image, since the image will be uploaded by the participants during the Survey ?

Comment: You pipe it just like in the example code I posted.  The only difference will be the QID number. In a subsequent question, go to Piped Text, choose the upload question and pick the url, then Qualtrics will insert the piped string for you.

Comment: Raouf - Great, glad it is working.  Please accept the answer.